# discord.js v13 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uptime')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js v13 bot with slash commands handler, I'm getting an error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uptime')`.

Here's my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("uptime")
    .setDescription("Check how long the bot has stayed on!"),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    let totalSeconds = client.uptime / 1000;
    let days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400);
    let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    totalSeconds %= 3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    let roundedSeconds = Math.round(seconds);
    let uptime = `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${roundedSeconds} seconds`;
    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [
        {
          color: "RANDOM",
          title: "**Uptime**",
          description: `It has been on for ${uptime}`,
        },
      ],
    });
  },
};
```

Here's what I defined `client` in my index.js file:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
  ],
});
```

Comment: It means `client` is `undefined`. I don't think you pass the `client` to the `execute` method. Make sure you call it with the correct arguments: `command.execute(interaction, client)`

Comment: `Parsing error: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this in a command file when it uses `client`:

```js
const { client } = interaction;
```

Answer (score -1):

in index.js add `module.exports = client;`

and in uptime.js add `const client = require('../../index.js')`